# Html.BeginForm does not work with nested forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

View1

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.TestViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home"))
{
    <div>Upper form</div>
    @Html.EditorForModel()
}
```

In EditorTemplates i have editor for this view

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.TestViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Test2", "Home"))
{
    <h2>TestViewModel</h2>
}
```

The actual result is

```
<form action="/Home/Test" method="post">    
    <div>Upper form</div>
    <div class="editor-label"><label for="Age">Age</label></div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Age must be a number." data-val-required="The Age field is required." id="Age" name="Age" type="number" value="0"> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Age" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
    <div class="editor-label"><label for="Name">Name</label></div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value=""> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
</form>
```

But the desire result should be

```
<form action="/Home/Test" method="post">    
    <div>Upper form</div>
    <form action="/Home/Test2" method="post">  
        <div class="editor-label"><label for="Age">Age</label></div>
        <div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Age must be a number." data-val-required="The Age field is required." id="Age" name="Age" type="number" value="0"> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Age" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
        <div class="editor-label"><label for="Name">Name</label></div>
        <div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value=""> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
    <form>
</form>
```

So my question is how can i nested the second BeginForm correctly ?

Comment: Nested forms are invalid html and are not supported. Do not use them.

Comment: illegal Html, you cannot have two nested form tags. what would you like to achieve?

Comment: The inner form is for a modal window. On this modal i have a few options. When i select the desire options i want to go to the server and get the information and then fill the fields for the outer form.

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned in the comments,nested forms are not a good idea.

What you should be doing is, Keep the form tag for your outer view as it is. For your model, Use normal html form elements without a form tag and use ajax to post data to the server from your java script and once you receive the data, you should be able to access the DOM elements using jQuery and update values as needed.

Something like this ( *The below code won't work with the markup you provided. This is just to give you an idea how to handle it generally*);

```
$(function(){

  $(document).on("click","#SomeBtnOnModelDialog",function(e){
    //Some submit button on model dialog was clicked
     e.preventDefault();

     //Read the data from model dialog elements using jquery 
     // and build an object to send to action method

     var dummyDataYouWantToSend = { name : "Read it using jquery",age:12};
     $.post("@Url.Action("SomeActionMethod","YourController")", dummyDataYouWantToSend ,
                                                       function (res){

      //Got some response. 
      //Now update some DOM elemets from the JSON response came back?
     // $("#SomeFormElementId").val(res.SomePropertyName);     
     });

  });

});
```